# System.TypeInitializationException in a match constructor

Tags: exception, f#, typeinitializeexception

I am trying to get a Discriminated Union type from a string in F# (4.0, VS2015). My code looks like this:

```
type FooOrBar =Foo | Bar
let FooOrBarFromString str =
    match str with 
    | "Foo" -> Foo
    | "Bar" -> Bar
    | _ -> raise (System.ArgumentException("Invalid input"))
```

The problem is, if the default condition is triggered, and the exception is raised, the Argument Exception is wrapped in a System.TypeInitializationException. Ex:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let result = FooOrBarFromString "baz"

An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Project.exe
```

Further complicating things, the VS2015 debugger then chokes and shows "Source Not Available". Only by inspecting the inner exception in the locals view can I see what is going on.

Is there a better way of setting this up so that errors in input data don't make debugging a massive pain?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I'm getting `System.ArgumentException("Invalid input")` as expected. (VS 2015)

Comment: The code you posted does not even compile because it is missing the `int` return value for `main`. If this is added the program will run as expected, that is it will throw the `System.ArgumentException`. You need to show some more of your code to let us reproduce the issue.